# uncaught exception error "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any idea why the following javascript/jquery code might produce the error message:
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"] ?

Code:

```
function deletereceipt(id){
 var $delconfdialog = $('<div id="dialog-confirm"></div')
                       .html('Are you sure you want to delete this receipt?')
                       .dialog({
                          autoOpen: true,
                          title: 'Delete Confirmation',
                          buttons: {
                             "Delete": function(){
                                $.post('Receipt.py',{'cm':'Delete','receiptid': obj},function(){
                                   $('#receiptrow'+id).remove();
                                });
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                             },
                             "Cancel" :function(){
                                $(this).dialog('close');   
                             }
                          }
                       });
    }
```

Comment: What browser? What version of jQuery/jQueryUI?

Comment: If that runs multiple times, it looks to me as if there'll be multiple copies of that added dialog `<div>` all with the same "id" value, and that would be bad.

Comment: firefox (latest version, I think), jQuery 1.4, not sure of the version of jQuery ui. Let's assume it only runs once (That's how I've been testing it to produce that error).

Comment: I think the right way to instantiate a div like that is $('<div>').attr('id','dialog-confirm'). I don't know if that is causing your issue though.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this error using the above code in JSFiddle with jquery 1.4.4 and jquery ui 1.8.7

Answer (score -1):

You are violating basic OOP principles here: you separate a method from its
object.

Comment: 1) What does OOP have to do with this? The OP's code has nothing to do with classes (or their JavaScript lookalikes)! 2) How does this solve the problem (the illegal operation exception)?